# Wordpress Job Manager not sending emails

Tags: wordpress, email, plugins, jobs

I have installed Job Manager plug in on my wordpress site and it is not sending emails. Its is working on one of my test server that has only Job Manager installed on it but it is not working on my client machine. There I have installed following plugins:

```
Exec-PHP  
Flexi Quote Rotator  
Gravity Forms  
Hide Title  
iframe  
Job Manager  
Linkable Title Html and Pho Widget by Penlamb  
Nivo Slider WordPress Plugin  
pageMash  
Shortcode Exec PHP  
Simple add pages or posts  
Vertical Scroll recent post  
Widget Context  
WP-Mail-SMTP  
WP Title 2
```

I have tried this by deactivation the WP-Mail-SMTP it does not send email then too. FYI WP-Mail-SMTP test email is going out well also when I create new users it send user information via email that means server is sending out email the issue might be with some other installed plug ins its own settings.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling the rest of the plugins?

If you don't want to disable them, you can also prevent WordPress from including them for a little while. Just go to your `/wp-content/plugins/` directory(through FTP client) and rename the directories of all plugins, except for `Job Manager`(for instance just add `_` at the begining of all directories). Make sure **not** to go to the plugins page, until you've restored the proper directories names - otherwise WordPress will disable the plugins(whereas when the plugin files don't exist and you're not on the Plugins page, their files are simply not included). Then see if Job Manager is still not sending emails.

You can also try installing all of the plugins on your test server and disable them one by one to see if it's a plugin conflict.